# Bootstrap Modal & YouTube Player tricks

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to do a small trick to allow auto playing/stopping of a youtube player embedded inside a bootstrap modal without using YouTube's API (since I i'll be needing more video provides in the future so I want to have a generic solution).

The trick works like that:

1. A Modal with a YouTube video (iframe) is shown and played [the video has `autoplay=1` source]
2. Once the modal is hidden (`hide event`) the iframe's src is captured within `data-iframe-src` attribute on that iframe and the original `src` of the iframe is set to `''`, this way the video stops playing.
3. Once I load back the video (`show event)` I'm trying to re-assign the `src` of the iframe from the `data-iframe-src` attribute but the only thing it sets is `?autoplay=1` I thought it might be because of the URL structure (`//youtube...`)

I tried to use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` but still no luck.

Here's my code:

```
$('#modal-video').on('hide show',function(e){
var $iframe = $(this).find('.video-wrap:visible').find('iframe'),
    iframe_src = '';

if ( e.type == 'hide' ) {
    // Snapshot
    $iframe.attr('data-iframe-src', encodeURIComponent( $iframe.attr('src') ) );

    // Clear iframe
    $iframe.attr('src','');
}
else {
    // Show and re-assign the iframe src
    $iframe.attr('src', decodeURIComponent( $iframe.attr('data-iframe-src') ) );
}
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yep, the '.video-wrap' is just a div that wraps the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the callbacks from bootstrap itself?

```
$(function() {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var src = $('#videowrapper').attr('data-iframe-src');
    $('#videowrapper').attr('src', src);
  });

  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#videowrapper').attr('src', '');
  });
});
```

This works as you want it to.

edit:

the data attribute is loaded from jQuery into the src attribute

```
<iframe id="videowrapper" width="560" height="315" src="" data-iframe-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SJTyY2csya8?autoplay=true" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

edit2:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/trk9vkat/

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 not 3 AFAIK 'shown.bs.modal' is for bootstrap 3, the issue is not the callbacks yet the address that is set on the 'shown' event shows only the '?autoplay=1' and not the full URL.

Comment: The BS version and event handling shouldn't matter - see my edit for an example of the iframe

Comment: Try that without the https:// in the beginning of the code, the embed code of youtube starts with //youtube to support both http/https. I think that causes the issue that when I'm setting the src from data-iframe-src it only sets '?autoplay=1' instead of the full URL.

Comment: Hmm now it works, maybe its because I have multiple videos? anyway, this works:

Answer (score 0):

Well I have multiple videos in the modal, something like this:

```
<div id="modal">
<div class="video-wrap video-1">
    iframe...
</div>
<div class="video-wrap video-2">
    iframe...
</div>
<div class="video-wrap video-3">
    iframe...
</div>
```

I think the issue was with the event names, it should be `hide` and `shown`, this way I can use the `:visible` selector.

And I did not have `data-iframe-src` set prior to closing the modal, now i've set it in the link the triggers the modal.

So this did the trick:

```
 // Video Trigger
    $('.play-video').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('video-id'),
        $video = $('.' + id),
        $iframe = $video.find('iframe');
        src = $iframe.attr('src');

    // Hide all
    $('.video-wrap').hide();

    // Show selected video
    $video.show();

    // Show modal
    center_modal('modal-video');

    // Autoplay video
    src = video_autoplay( src );
    if ( typeof( $iframe.attr('data-iframe-src') ) == 'undefined' ) {
        $iframe.attr('data-iframe-src', src);
    }
});



// Show / Hide
    $('#modal-video').on('hide shown',function(e){
    var $iframe = $(this).find('.video-wrap:visible').find('iframe');
    if ( e.type == 'hide' ) {
        $iframe.attr('src','');
    }
    else {
        if ( $iframe.attr('src') == '' ) {
            $iframe.attr('src',$iframe.attr('data-iframe-src'));
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your time & help! ;-)